# How can i highlight a row in PHP/CSS?

Tags: php, html, css

I have a database of products and I have a table called "status". I want that the background color of the row be green when the product is available and red when it's unavailable. How can I do that?

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($query_run) > 0)
                                        {
                                            foreach($query_run as $items)
                                            {
                                                ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td><?= $items['id']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?= $items['name']; ?></td>
                                                    <td><?= $items['type']; ?></td> 
                                                    <td><?= $items['status']; ?></td>

                                                </tr>
                                                <?php
                                            }
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            ?>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td colspan="4">No results</td>
                                                </tr>
                                            <?php
                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: Please define what you mean by "available"

Answer (score 0):

Make two classes in your CSS, one for available and one for unavailable:

```
<style>
.available {
    background-color: #00ff00;
}
.unavailable {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
</style>
```

This allows you to assign whatever of styling you want in one place. Maybe you also want bold or italic, whatever. You can just add that to the CSS in one spot and you don't have to touch the PHP code in the future. Then just reference those classes in the appropriate row tag:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($items) > 0) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // <tr class="available">
    }
} else {
    // <tr class="unavailable">
}
```